# How can I reuse AuthorizationHandler logic for different AuthorizationRequirements?

Tags: c#, authorization, asp.net-identity, asp.net-authorization, resource-based-authorization

I am trying to find a way to imperatively authorize resources in an asp.net razor pages application. So far, I have followed the guide found in this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/resourcebased?view=aspnetcore-8.0. But, I am running into a problem where I want to be able to reuse authentication logic for various different requirements, without having to define a new class which inherits that specific requirement.

For example, I have a location object that I want to be viewable under the following conditions:

1. If the user is of the role Admin or Master, or
2. If the user is a part of the Zone which the Location is also a part of.

I have successfully built a requirement, and two handlers to implement this logic as follows:

```
public class IsAdminOrHigherHandler : AuthorizationHandler<AccessLocationRequirement>
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(
        AuthorizationHandlerContext context,
        AccessLocationRequirement requirement)
    {
        if (context.User.IsInRole(SD.Roles.Admin.ToString()) || context.User.IsInRole(SD.Roles.Master.ToString()))
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}

public class InLocationsZoneHandler : AuthorizationHandler<AccessLocationRequirement, Location>
{
    private readonly IUserService _userService;
    public InLocationsZoneHandler(IUserService userService)
    {
        _userService = userService;
    }
    protected override async Task HandleRequirementAsync(
        AuthorizationHandlerContext context,
        AccessLocationRequirement requirement,
        Location resource)
    {
        User? user = await _userService.GetUserFromContextAsync();
        if (user == null)
        {
            context.Fail();
            return;
        }
        if (user.Zones.Any(z => z.Id == resource.Zone.Id))
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

I then register a policy that takes this requirement:

```
    options.AddPolicy("CanAccessLocation",
        policy => policy.AddRequirements(new AccessLocationRequirement()));
```

This works great, but my question is that when I want to define a new policy for defining rules for **editing** a location, I want to avoid rewriting this logic just because the requirement has changed. For example, my condition for editing a location are as follows:

1. If the user is Admin or Master, or
2. If the user is a part of the Zone which the Location is also a part of AND they have a role of ZoneManager.

As we can see, to edit a location, you may fulfill the requirement simply by fulfilling the logic laid out in the `IsAdminOrHigherHandler` method, but because the `IsAdminOrHigherHandler` inherits from `AuthorizationHandler<AccessLocationRequirement>` and not `AuthorizationHandler<EditLocationRequirement>`, we would have to rewrite this method.

How can I share Authorization Handler logic for different Requirements? Or is there a better method?

Answer (score 0):

You could have `BaseRequirement` which will be inherited by your `AccessLocationRequirement` and `EditLocationRequirement`. Then your `IsAdminOrHigherHandler` would impelement the `BaseRequirement`.

That way your every requirement would inherit from your base which handler holds logic for Admin and Master roles.

Something like this:

```
public class BaseRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
}
```

Then you gonna have:

```
public class AccessLocationRequirement : BaseRequirement 
{

}
```

and your other requirement:

```
public class EditAccessLocationRequirement : BaseRequirement 
{

}
```

Then your handler code would be:

```
public class IsAdminOrHigherHandler : AuthorizationHandler<BaseRequirement>
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(
        AuthorizationHandlerContext context,
        BaseRequirement requirement)
    {
        if (context.User.IsInRole(SD.Roles.Admin.ToString()) || context.User.IsInRole(SD.Roles.Master.ToString()))
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}

public class InLocationsZoneHandler : AuthorizationHandler<AccessLocationRequirement, Location>
{
    private readonly IUserService _userService;
    public InLocationsZoneHandler(IUserService userService)
    {
        _userService = userService;
    }
    protected override async Task HandleRequirementAsync(
        AuthorizationHandlerContext context,
        AccessLocationRequirement requirement,
        Location resource)
    {
        User? user = await _userService.GetUserFromContextAsync();
        if (user == null)
        {
            context.Fail();
            return;
        }
        if (user.Zones.Any(z => z.Id == resource.Zone.Id))
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
            return;
        }
    }
}
// And code of your other handler
```

And just register handlers and policy:

```
services.AddScoped<IAuthorizationHandler, IsAdminOrHigherHandler>();
services.AddScoped<IAuthorizationHandler, InLocationsZoneHandler >();
//and your other handler
```

and just add your policies with requirements.

Comment: Interesting solution, then would the base requirement Inherit from a generic AuthorizationHandler<TRequirement>?

Comment: @kj49 , actually not - everything that extends BaseRequirement has they own handler and handler for BaseRequirement. I updated my answer - my original one was written from phone.

Comment: Thanks, I’m still trying to understand this a little. Is naming our parent class BaseRequirement appropriate if it defines access for Admin users only or would you suggest being more explicit?

Comment: @kj49 , you can name it the way you want. This was for sake of example.